# Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces by Do Carmo 3-4 Problem 12 and 13

Tags: differential-geometry

I am doing section 3-4 exercise 12 and 13 of Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces by Do Carmo and was stuck on those problems. Problem 12 is:

> Prove that if w is a differentiable vector field on a compact surface S and $\alpha(t)$ is the maximal trajectory of w with $\alpha(0)=p\in S$, then $\alpha(t)$ is defined for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

Problem 13 is:

> Construct a differentiable vector field on an open disk of the plane (which is not compact) such that a maximal trajectory $\alpha(t)$ is not defined for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ (this shows that the compactness condition of Exercise 12 is essential).

For number 12, there is a solution in the back of textbook which reads,

> For every q$\in$S, there exists a neighborhood U of q and an interval ($-\epsilon$,$\epsilon$), $\epsilon$>0, such that the trajectory $\alpha$(t), with $\alpha$(0)=q, is defined in ($-\epsilon$,$\epsilon$). By compactness, it is possible to cover S with a finite number of such neighborhoods. Let $\epsilon_0$=minimum of the corresponding $\epsilon$'s. If $\alpha(t)$ is defined for t<$t_0$ and is not defined for $t_0$, take $t_1 \in (0,t_0)$, with $|t_0-t|<\epsilon /2$. Consider the trajectory $\beta(t)$ of w, with $\beta(t_1)=\alpha(t_1)$, and obtain a contradiction."

Is the contradiction supposed to be the fact that $\beta(t)$ is defined than a larger interval of $\alpha(t)$, thus contradicting $\alpha(t)$ being maximal trajectory?

For problem 13, I was think of the open disk $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}|0<x^2+y^2<1\}$ with the vector field $w(x,y)=(\frac{1}{x^2+1},\frac{1}{y^2+1})$, which gives trajectory $\alpha(t)=(arctan(t)+C_1,arctan(t)+C_2)$ for constants $C_1,C_2$. Would this work?